# Cassandra Upgrade 5 node cluster from 2.2.8 to 3.0

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I have got stuck in Upgrading Cassandra from 2.2.8 to 3.0 which is 5 node cluster.

without loosing any data consistency.

Thanks.
Siva

Comment: We need alot more information to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You may find this helpful:

https://myopsblog.wordpress.com/2017/12/04/upgrade-cassandra-cluster-from-2-x-to-3-x/

In short:

- shutdown node (only one a time):
- backup configs
- remove old cassandra packages (keep the data files!)
- install new cassandra packages
- 'diff' the old and new configs and modify the new one to meet your needs
- start the upgraded node
- use `nodetool upgradesstables` to rewrite the sstables
- see the the node is up and running, then
- repeat for all other nodes (but copy the configs)

Concering consistency - if you have enough replicas and appropriate consistency levels (e.g. not CL.ALL) this works online without interruption.

Comment: Thank you and please share ansible script which you used in Cassandra upgradation process